# Bootstrap divs collapsing into another div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello Stackoverflow users,

I am creating a website and the start was going pretty well until I came to the point I will explain in a bit, I have already been trying and looking over my code for hours and Google'd all kinds of things but couldn't find anything similar to my issue. [Here's an image of how the webpages currently look, the first obviously medium/large, the middle size small and the last one is extra small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wdbs.png).

So, as you can tell from the images something is going wrong, I expected a div not being closed right or something but I can't find anything like that in my code! Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <base href="/duo-uniek/" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Home: Welkom - Duo-Uniek.nl</title>
        <script src="javascript/jQuery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/banner.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link id="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fluid-container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 padding-horizontal border-bottom header">
                <div class="list-group list-inline list-unstyled text-center">
                    <span class="list-group-item col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-sm-push-2 col-md-push-4 active">Home</span>
                    <a class="list-group-item col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-sm-push-2 col-md-push-4" href="page/media.html">Media</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-sm-push-2 col-md-push-4" href="page/info.html">Info</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-sm-push-2 col-md-push-4" href="page/contact.html">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
                <div class="banner hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-12 border-bottom no-padding styling" style="height: 500px;">
                    <div class="innerBanner col-md-12">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="banner visible-sm-block col-sm-12 border-bottom no-padding styling" style="height: 350px;">
                    <div class="innerBanner col-sm-12">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="banner visible-xs-block col-xs-12 border-bottom no-padding styling" style="height: 200px;">
                    <div class="innerBanner col-xs-12">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center padding-horizontal   border-bottom styling">
                <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-3 padding-horizontal" style="background-color: black;">
                    <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color: white;">
                        <p>Test</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-3 padding-horizontal" style="background-color: black;">
                    <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color: white;">
                        <p>Test</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-3 padding-horizontal" style="background-color: black;">
                    <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="background-color: white;">
                        <p>Test</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: orange;">
                <p>Home</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is from 'show page source' as my code is mostly being generated by PHP but unless I'm really stupid I checked everything and nothing was wrong. I really don't know what to do, everything I tried didn't help and I really have to get this fixed... I hope someone here can!

Best regards,
Jesse

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? Also, you should use something like [Bootlint](http://www.bootlint.com/#byDirect) to check your code.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it before, I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6 for people who will ever read this question. It has already been solved by Guruwanabe but thank you for your reaction too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo `col-sx-12` it should be `col-xs-12`

Comment: Oh my god! You're right and it also fixed my problem!!!! I'm so embarrassed that this took me a few hours and even asking Stackoverflow for help haha

 Thank you a lot!